# Share an audio file via sharesheet

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to share an audio file using iOS' sharesheet functionality. I'm having trouble getting the audio file audio file into the sharesheet for sharing. As it stands, there is not and attachment or audio file added to the email (for example).

I have the following code which retrieves the audio file. I am able to send it explicitly as an email using the `MFMailComposeViewController`, but would instead like to 'throw' it at the sharesheet to allow user to upload to email / dropbox / google drive the file.

Is this possible?

```
    let objectsToShare: NSMutableArray = []

    let docsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let soundFilePath = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let fileContent = fileManager.contentsAtPath(soundFilePath)


    objectsToShare.addObject(fileContent!)

    if let objects = objectsToShare as [AnyObject]? {
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objects, applicationActivities: nil)

        if let subject = noteTitle.text as String? {
            activityVC.setValue(subject, forKey: "subject")
        }

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the file *content* into `objectsToShare`. `activityVC` can share the *content* but does not know it is a file to be shared.

I think you need a [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDocumentInteractionController/URL) instead. Like this untested code:

```
var dic:UIDocumentInteractionController? // has to be instance variable not buried in a method, or the dic is deallocated before it can open the file.
func shareFile(filePath:String, fileName: String, from:UIBarButtonItem) {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    dic = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL:url)
    dic?.UTI = fileName
    dic?.presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem(from, animated: true)
}
```

If you make `dic` a local variable inside the `shareFile` method, it tends to get deallocated before the file has been opened and that gets you a `Couldn't get file size for (null)` error. Make it an instance variable of the class instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll check it out tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: This was more than enough to point me in the right direction. Many thanks :)